Use output of a bash command as parameter input of a job template in Azure DevOps pipeline
There is a job template (externally managed). I want to use this template in my pipeline. I have to provide a number of parameters for this template to work. I would like to dynamically generate the value for one of these parameters, namely a password.
I thought of using pwgen for this like so:
  jobs:
    - job: generate_key_password
      steps:
        - bash: |
            set -e
            echo "Installing pwgen"
            sudo apt install pwgen && echo "Successfully installed pwgen"
            pw=$(pwgen -y -s 25 1)
          displayName: Installing pwgen

I then would like to use the output of this step in a template:
- template: /x/y/z/a-template.yml@some-repo
  parameters:
    theParameterName: <this should be the password I generated>

I have used vso in the past to pass on variables from one job to another, but this doesn't seem to be possible in the context of my task (I cannot set dependsOn). Is there any straightforward strategy to pass on the variable and use it in a subsequent template job or not?
Tied together, it would look like this:
stages:
  - stage: the_stage
    jobs:
      - job: generate_key_password
        steps:
          - bash: |
              set -e
              echo "Installing pwgen"
              sudo apt install pwgen && echo "Successfully installed pwgen"
              pw=$(pwgen -y -s 25 1)
            displayName: Installing pwgen
      - template: /x/y/z/a-template.yml@some-repo
        parameters:
          theParameterName: <this should be the password I generated>


Runtime generated pw can not be render in parameters. theParameterName would throw an error to notice to provide the value, because it render at the beginning and the pw are not produced out.

Can you split into two stage, pw generated job in stage1 and a-template.yml job in stage2, so that you can set dependsOn on the stage to avoid on the job template.

@wenbo Yes, that's a possibility

"I cannot set dependsOn" - this is a design problem. It should be possible to set some parameters such as job dependencies, conditions, timeouts and others in order to create configurable and extensible job templates. Consider asking the template author(s) to add the dependsOn parameter and others that might make your life (and others') easier.

If you can set dependsOn on stage level, you can transfer the variable to next stage. Please refer to my sample below:
main.yml:
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

stages:
- stage: One
  jobs:
  - job: A
    steps:
      - bash: echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=MyVar;isOutput=true]testpwd"
        name: ProduceVar

- stage: Two
  dependsOn: One
  variables:
    varFromA: $[ stageDependencies.One.A.outputs['ProduceVar.MyVar'] ]
  jobs:
    - template: template4.yml
      parameters:
        pwd: $(varFromA)

template4.yml
parameters:
  - name: pwd
    type: string

jobs:
- job: job2
  steps:
  - script: echo ${{ parameters.pwd}}

The execution result:

Or you can consider to put the template in a new pipeline. You can generate the password in 1st pipeline, use rest api Runs - Run Pipeline to trigger the 2nd build pipeline, and set the parameter to 2nd pipeline for template parameter.
You can find the sample in my answer here.

By default, stages run one after the other so your example should work without dependsOn: One, right?

Yes, it works. But i prefer to add the dependsOn: One to be more clear.

"I prefer to add the dependsOn: One to be more clear" - yep, I agree.
